# Co-Variance of Zero and Non-Zero mean random variables

Tags: mean, covariance

Is the value of co-variance function for non-zero mean random variables different from the value of co-variance function when random variables have a zero-mean?

I think yes based on this:
For a random vector $X$
$K_{X} = E[(X-\mu_X)(X-\mu_X)^H]$ 
or
$K_{X} = R_{X} - m_X.{m_X}^H$

But I am not sure.

Answer (score 3):

Covariance is a bilinear function meaning, among other things, that
\begin{align}
\operatorname{cov}(X+a,Y+b) &= \operatorname{cov}(X,Y)+\operatorname{cov}(X,b) + \operatorname{cov}(a,Y) + \operatorname{cov}(a,b)\\
&= \operatorname{cov}(X,Y)+0 + 0 + 0\\
&= \operatorname{cov}(X,Y).
\end{align}
Thus, $\hat{X} = X+a$ sand $\hat{Y} = Y+b$, which happen to be random
variables with means $\mu_X + a$ and $\mu_Y + b$ respectively, have the *same*
covariance as $X$ and $Y$.

> **In short, means do not matter.**

Comment: This is understandable. Though what exactly does equation of Kx, Rx and mx tells me? What is the intuition behind it since it really is not helping me with any kind of information about either Kx or Rx.

Comment: The _definition_ of the covariance matrix $K_X$ is $K_{X} = E[(X-\mu_X)(X-\mu_X)^H]$. If you expand out the matrix product, you can prove that $K_{X} = E[XX^H]- m_X.{m_X}^H = R_X - m_X.{m_X}^H$  where $R_X$ is _defined_ as $E[XX^H]$. "But Ha!" you say, "that _proves_ what I have been claiming all along: that $K_X$ depends on the mean!" Alas, it is not so unless you have a **different** definition (that you have not as yet revealed to stats.SE) of $R_X$.

Answer (score 0):

The formula doesn't change, but as you can see from your formula, the covariance of a zero-mean RV does simplify to (using your notation):

$K_X = E(XX^T) - E(X)[E(X)]^T = E(XX^T) - \mathbf{0} = R_X$.

Where $\mathbf{0}$ is a $D*D$ matrix of zeros and $D$ is the dimensionality of your random variable.